# Can an Android WebView do a translationX animation with hardware acceleration?

Tags: android, webview, android-animation

I had read somewhere that hardware acceleration should work for all built in Android views; however, when I try to do a slide animation with a WebView the entire Web Content goes blank for the duration of the animation.

I'll write a little app so if you would like to see it for yourselves, you can try. The app will do a slide animation every time a page loads in the WebView. We'll slide between an ImageView and a WebView. The ImageView will just contain a screenshot of the WebView itself. Stick the following code in onCreate for your activity:

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

final ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        myWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.buildDrawingCache();
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(myWebView.getDrawingCache()));
        myWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        myImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

        ObjectAnimator webViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myWebView, "translationX", myWebView.getWidth(), 0);
        webViewAnimator.setDuration(SLIDE_DURATION);
        ObjectAnimator imageViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myImageView, "translationX", 0, -myWebView.getWidth());
        imageViewAnimator.setDuration(SLIDE_DURATION);

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                myWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
                myImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        set.playTogether(webViewAnimator, imageViewAnimator);
        set.start();
    }
}
```

Ensure you have android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your Manifest.xml

Also, in your main_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now every time you load a page, there will be a slide transition between an ImageView (containing a screenshot of the WebView), and the WebView itself.

**The bug is not reproducable in the JellyBean simulator, however it does happen on all ICS/JellyBean devices tested so far...**

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Note that although I can simply disable Hardware Acceleration on the WebView by setting it's Layer Type to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE and this will fix the "blanking out" issue, I would like to keep Hardware Acceleration enabled because of the rendering benefits.