# 9 tiles Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to build an application which is composed by 9 tiles using a webview. Each one of them is an .html file that I load into the webview, and the navigation happens via swiping.

This is the code for swiping:

```
boolean result = false;
  try {
    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();

    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
      if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
        if (diffX > 0)
          onSwipeRight();
        else
          onSwipeLeft();
      }
    } else {
      if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
        if (diffY > 0)
          onSwipeBottom();
        else
          onSwipeTop();
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
  }
  return result;
}
```

where each `onSwipe<Direction>()` method is structured as follows:

```
private void onSwipeTop() {
  if (row < MAX_ROW) {
    row++;
    loadUrl(Direction.UP);
    System.out.println("Swipe Top!");
  }
}
```

then the animation is handled by this code that was found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995909/can-an-android-webview-do-a-translationx-animation-with-hardware-acceleration):

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.buildDrawingCache();
    imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache()));
    webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    ObjectAnimator webViewAnimator = null;
    ObjectAnimator imageViewAnimator = null;

    switch (currentDirection) {
      case LEFT:
        System.out.println(">> Left!");
        webViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webView, "translationX", webView.getWidth(), 0);
        imageViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX", 0, -webView.getWidth());
        break;
      case RIGHT:
        System.out.println(">> Right!");
        webViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webView, "translationX", -webView.getWidth(), 0);
        imageViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX", 0, webView.getWidth());
        break;
      case UP:
        System.out.println(">> Up!");
        webViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webView, "translationY", webView.getHeight(), 0);
        imageViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationY", -webView.getHeight());
        break;
      case BOTTOM:
        System.out.println(">> Bottom!");
        webViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(webView, "translationY", -webView.getHeight(), 0);
        imageViewAnimator =
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationY", webView.getHeight());
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    imageViewAnimator.setDuration(SLIDE_DURATION);
    webViewAnimator.setDuration(SLIDE_DURATION);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
    });

    set.playTogether(imageViewAnimator, webViewAnimator);
    set.start();
```

My problem: as soon as I change the swiping direction, the ImageView doesn't appear anymore, and is substituted by a white screen, while I would like to get a smooth transition effect. Can anybody help me? Or maybe suggest another solution? Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with webviews and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476151/webview-flashing-with-white-background-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled-an) problems solution solves my problem. Shortly I disabled hardware acceleration of my activity. Hope this helps.